# what is Corrupted serialized SCRAM error?

Tags: erlang, xmpp, ejabberd, mongoose-im

I am using mongooseim and suddenly I started getting the below error:
**[warning] Corrupted serialized SCRAM: <<>>** and no longer able to connect with the users. I am unable to find if somehow I enabled authentication other than PLAIN TEXT authentication.

Also, If I register a new user from the terminal command like :**mongooseimctl register user10 localhost pass**, it always works. But from the database all the other users look same like user10 but all those don't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ohh I find it myself, uppercase characters are not allowed in the username due to which it was throwing error the above error and make sure that pass_details vale should be null.

Comment: Ideally, you would use the `mongooseimctl` command interface - https://mongooseim.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide/Getting-started/#registering-a-user. If you need to ultimately register users from the NodeJS server, you can first register a few with the command line to see how they get serialized to the DB.

Comment: Yes, erszcz. But the issue is username should only be created with lowercase and I was creating it with mixed uppercase and lowercase

Comment: Indeed, it is an issue. That's why `mongooseimctl` can help: `$ ./bin/mongooseimctl register jAnE localhost pass123` leads to an `{passwd,{<<"jane">>,<<"localhost">>},<<"pass123">>}` entry in the database.

Comment: Thats Awesome. BTW, I only see you helping me here for mongoose and ejabberd issue most of the time. Are you work at ejabberd/mongooseIM or in some other company or freelancer, just curious?

Comment: Indeed, I work at Erlang Solutions - the company behind MongooseIM :) Not that I'm hiding this fact - it's in my profile.

Comment: Thanks erszcz . Your MongooseIM product is really awesome and the best part is free so that I can experiment and play with it. :)